# Zend Framework 1, AWS S3 Adapter Supporting V4

Tags: zend-framework, amazon-s3

In a project we are using ZendFramework 1 and we need to add S3 support for some file operations. The logical consideration was Zend_Cloud_StorageService so we can easily switch to different types of storage just by changing the adapter. However AWS newest regions only support V4 authentication and as such the default S3 adapter that comes with zend is not compatible.

```
$storage = Zend_Cloud_StorageService_Factory::getAdapter([
        Zend_Cloud_StorageService_Factory::STORAGE_ADAPTER_KEY => 'Zend_Cloud_StorageService_Adapter_S3',
        Zend_Cloud_StorageService_Adapter_S3::AWS_ACCESS_KEY   => '....key....',
        Zend_Cloud_StorageService_Adapter_S3::AWS_SECRET_KEY   => '...secret...',
        Zend_Cloud_StorageService_Adapter_S3::BUCKET_NAME => '..bucket-name..'
    ]);

$storage->listItems('/');
```

AWS response is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>InvalidRequest</Code><Message>The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256.</Message> 
    <RequestId>...5F343398....</RequestId>
    <HostId>.....bliEk9xnCWr....</HostId>
</Error>
```

Is there some updated S3 adapter that could work with the Zend Cloud Storage Service for [Zend Framework 1](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/de/zend.cloud.storageservice.html)